# How do I create a data frame with every possible permutation of integers with certain constraints?

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I have ten columns: n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10.

The values in a single row must add up to exactly 10, and all of the values must be non-negative integers less than or equal to 5.

I'd like to make a DataFrame with every possible permutation according to the constraints that I've just described. The order matters (i.e., [5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] and [5,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] should both be separate rows).

Here's my attempt:

```
import itertools as it

permutations = [i for i in it.permutations(range(0,6), 10) if sum(i)==10]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=permutations,columns=['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6','x7','x8','x9','x10'])
```

The problem is that there are zero rows in `df`. The array `permutations` is empty. I don't see why that is. If I replace `it.permutations` with `it.combinations_with_replacement`, the length of the resulting list is 30. Why does `it.permutations` return nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It's an easy fix!

Since order matters, you're actually looking for **`itertools.product`** (I know, it's a weird name). Here's the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product.

## Solution:

```py
import itertools as it
permutations = [i for i in it.product(range(6), repeat=10) if sum(i) == 10]
```

Comment: You didn't misread, I miswrote. I intended to state that the integers must be less than or equal to 5. I edited my question to clarify that.

Comment: Ah, got it! I’m removing the additional notes then :)

Comment: Also, I think the problem might read non-negative integers, as 0 is not a positive integer.

Comment: Oops, fixed. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a permutation of 10 items from a list of 6 items.  (Maybe "permutation" doesn't mean what you think it means.)

Here's one way to get what you want (though its gonna take a while to run):

```
permutations = []
for p in [i for i in it.combinations_with_replacement(range(0,6), 10) if sum(i)==10]:
    permutations += [x for x in set(it.permutations(p))]
```

(Explanation: each `p` is way of choosing 10 *sets* of values with the proper sum.  The we use `permutations` to find all the ways to order that set of values.)

Comment: Is there any way for me to get what I'm trying to get, then? Because using `it.combinations_with_replacement` just gives me a list of 30 elements, when there should be more. I guess I need something like permutations_with_replacements? Although I still might be misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You chose the incorrect way to repeat things.

```
import itertools as it

permutations = [i for i in it.product(*it.repeat(range(6),10)) if sum(i)==10]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=permutations,columns=['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6','x7','x8','x9','x10'])
```

This should get about 85228 results.